# Does The Ancestry Gem Work With Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

Only mentions Rails 3 in the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) - does anyone know if it's compatible with Rails 4?

I ask because it looks like it's been updated to handle Ruby 2.1.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [travis build](https://travis-ci.org/stefankroes/ancestry), tests pass with active record 4.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it works. We've been using it in one of our recent projects. You can also look at travis.yml file in the repo. It was tested to work with ActiveRecord 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's compatible with Rails 4, but you need to add `:parent_id` to permit params in your controller.

Comment: I'm looking at using ancestry with Rails 5. Where do you add `:parent_id`? As a field on the database table to add the tree stuff to?